# Showing the current selection in a listview

Tags: android, android-listview

As seen in the tablet version of gmail and google talk I am trying to show the current selection in a listview. I know this is not standard practice and should be avoided when necessary.in my program the listview is alway on the screen and the item clicked shows a new fragment to the right (similar to gmail and google talk).

To avoid the user from guessing what item has been selected I would like to show the current selection, I tried creating a selector but after it is clicked it changes back to the normal background.

how can I achieve this?

this is my selector xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg2" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_focused="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected_bg2" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected_bg2" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_selected="true" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected_bg2" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected_bg2" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_selected="false" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected_bg2" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_selected="true" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected_bg2" android:state_pressed="true"/>



</selector>
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

What Gmail and similar apps use is the `activated` state, with an appropriate row layout. See:

- [Setting Android Background & Persistence Menu Bar - Using attribute on older versions causes crash - Is there a theme /pattern approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274982/setting-android-background-persistence-menu-bar-using-attribute-on-older-ver)
- [Change colour of activated list item background on Honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588750/change-colour-of-activated-list-item-background-on-honeycomb)

In a nutshell, you:

- Use a row layout with an activated background (e.g., `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1`)
- Use `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)` on your `ListView`
- "Check" the row that should be activated using `setItemChecked()` on your `ListView` to enable the "activated" state and have the persistent highlight

Comment: excellent worked just as i wanted plus explanation if i need to change background color!

Comment: Very helpful as I was trying to highlight my textviews when selected, but duplicate highlights were happening. Your explanation simply solved my issue and I no more need to make my child views as setSelected(true). Thanks

Comment: @Pinch: It's not supposed to work on Android 2.x. The `activated` concept was not introduced until Android 3.0. Since there are no Android 2.x tablets of significance, you do not need `activated` on Android 2.x, and the first link in the answer shows how to set it up to only use `activated` on Android 3.0+.

Comment: @Pinch and others. You might try googling for workaaorund that uses state_checked. It is a bit more work though. You have to implement Checkable interface in your views and then you have to write correct selectors regarding the state_checked.

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, this works totally fine with CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL as well.

Comment: If anyone was wondering, this works for custom row layouts as well. All you have to do is add `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` to your listrow layout.

Answer (score 9):

Your other option is to set the background of your custom list item to **android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"**

Answer (score 8):

If you use a custom layout for each row:

1. create a selector with **android:state_activated="true"**
2. apply it as the background of the custom layout.

an example of the selector drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/android_green" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: This worked for me whereas other method didn't! Thanks!

From the code:

listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
listview.setItemChecked(3,true);
listview.setSelection(3);

Here the "3" is the index of item to be selected. setItemChecked applies the drawable color background and setSelection makes the list automatically scroll to that item.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me

1. override the global ListView Style in your theme

   `<item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListView</item>`
2. define your style

   `<style name="MyListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
       <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/listview_background_selector</item>
   </style>`
3. define the selector listview_background_selector.xml

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
       <item android:drawable="@color/ListViewBackGroundColorPressed" android:state_activated="true" />
   </selector>`
4. set the background of your listview-item-layout

   `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"`