# Keep state of selected elements when data are changing in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, state

I have an activity with a list of Products (like a shopping list), in which we can choose the number of product units.

The activity contains EditText with TextWatcher and a ListView with a personal Adapter (extends BaseAdapter).

When I type a key in the EditText, the listView of products is refreshed with the new data.

But I would like to keep the state of my selected data.

For example, I type a reference in the EditText, then the listView contains 3 datas (A, B, C), I choose A, and type 5 units of it, then I type a new reference in the EditText (A and B disappears).

The listView contain only C, but I remove my search and go back to A, B, C.

the problem, the product A is unselected and have 0 of units (the 5 units have disappeared).

I would like to keep the selected products and the units even if I change my search in the EditText.

How to do that please ?

Here is a code snippet :

The layout of the activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText  
        android:id="@+building_list/search_box" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Filter by reference"
        android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|none|textAutoComplete|none|textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/productListView">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Adapter :

```
public class AdapterProduct extends BaseAdapter {   
    private List<Product> lstProduct;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public AdapterProduct(Context context, List<Product> listP) {
        lstProduct = listP;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckedLinearLayout layoutItem;

        if (convertView == null) {      
            layoutItem = (CheckedLinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_product, parent, false);
            final ViewHolderProduct viewHolder;
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderProduct();

            viewHolder.btPlusAmount = (Button)layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.btPlusAmount);
            viewHolder.btPlusAmount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Product p = (Product) viewHolder.product.getTag();
                    p.setAmount(p.getAmount()+1);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            layoutItem = (CheckedLinearLayout) convertView;
            ((ViewHolderProduct) layoutItem.getTag()).btPlusAmount.setTag(lstProduct.get(position));
        }

        ViewHolderProduct viewHolder = (ViewHolderProduct) layoutItem.getTag();
        viewHolder.amount.setText(String.valueOf(lstProduct.get(position).getAmount()));
}

static class ViewHolderProduct {
    protected TextView amount;
    protected Button btPlusAmount;
}
}
```

And the AsyncTask with TextWatcher :

```
AsyncTask
doInBackground =>
    modelProduct = new AdapterProduct(leContext, 
                        ProductJSON.getService().searchProducts(leContext, url, params[0])); //params[0] = the text of EditText


private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

        //AsyncTask task
        task.execute(s.toString());
    }
};
```

Comment: 1. save your selected position from list view. 2. using that position get you product which is selected. 3. save that product(which is selected) 4. when all text are remove from edit text or when you refresh you list view with new data then if saved product in list the assine that position selected (using save selected position in step 3)..... its vey simple..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I let you check my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15070130/1685143).

1) Basically, add a new attribute to your adapter. A simple int[] is enough. Store the number of products selected inside.

2) Each time you build the View of a row of your `ListView`, check the number of products selected.

3)Make sure to update the number of products selected when you click on the button. Also, make sure to resize/update this array when your List changes. Call notifyDataSetChanged() Each Time you click on a product.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and I will answer you in order to close the post or to ask new questions ;)

Comment: Ok then I have an ArrayList with selected Products, and On the constructor of the Adapter, when new datas coming, I update number of products.

Before notifyDataSetChanged I update the ArrayList of selected products (accessible in a static way).

It's ok for me, thank a lot !