# Update alpha of a image inside ListView

Tags: android

I am using a ListView with a BaseAdapter. Each row in the ListView has a LinealLayout and 2 ImageView.

My problem is that I need to change the alpha of the image from my Activity but I don't manage to do it.

I have tried to do it like that:

```
View v = listAdapter.getView(2, null, null);
ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.secondImage);
img.setAlpha(1000);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But after that, I can't see the new changes. Another way that I thought was using **listView.getChildAt()** but it always returns a Null object. What is the right way?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to set correct answers in your previous questions.

Comment: You could use the same method I described [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15070130/1685143

Comment: The situation is different. At the beginning all the images don't have alpha, so then I have to set it. So getView() is called before.

Comment: Well just call notifyDataSetChanged() once you have changed the alpha values. This will redraw the View.