# How to mark a listview item?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, custom-adapter, android-selector

I know this has been discussed many times in questions like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview) one.
But I have to say it doesn't work for me.

**What I wanted to achieve is to mark a ListView item through my CustomAdapter** in a special situation. So, not through the user and click listeners. I have a working solution by setting a background drawable to the convertView.

Now I want to change this and let do a selector the job, which is the cleaner solution. But I can't get it to work. There is no problem to set the behavior for pressing an item and set a different color. **But I can't mark it as selected after I pressed the item.**

I tried different combinations with my listview_item_selector and listview_selector. And I think, that I have missed something very general. That's why I made a setup just to figure out how to mark an item after it was pressed.

Here's my list_item_selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_normal"/>
</selector>
```

And my listview_selector setted to the ListView as selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/state_pressed"></item>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_item"/>   
</selector>
```

As I said `state_pressed` is working. But `state_selected` drives me nuts.

At least my layout for the custom items:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_item_selector">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/list_tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFEE"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/list_tv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFEEEE"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are missing a state, you need to mark the row as activated and have the drawable that indicates the row as selected for the activated state

see my question for an example

[Showing the current selection in a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729517/showing-the-current-selection-in-a-listview)

then use

```
listview.setItemChecked(position,true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I didn't know about that state and that I have to set the activatedBackgroundIndicator. Saved my day