# Changing the state of selector after list item has been pressed

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I've used a list selector to display different colours depending on the the state (selected and otherwise). Below is my listselector code:

```
//Orange on selected
<item android:drawable="@color/orange" android:state_selected="true"/> 

//Black otherwise
<item android:drawable="@color/black"/>
```

In my main activity i also set the view as : view.setSelected(true);

However after selecting a list item, the colour is still orange.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: `However after selecting a list item, the color is still orange` isnt that was you want? if you are setting something as selecting then it will appear orange and not black

Comment: @tyczj yes that's what i want. But after i go on to do other things within the same view, the colour doesn't change. The list is within a sliding drawer.

Comment: you have to remove the selection then. Are you just trying to highlight a row to show its selected?

Comment: @tyczj yes i'm just trying to highlight the row.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong state for the color, you need to use the `activated` state.

check out my question I had on this

[Showing the current selection in a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729517/showing-the-current-selection-in-a-listview)